# Why TemplateBinding can't binding Button.Content?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new in WPF and i'm executing some simulations to try understanding the `binding` "things" (Like `{Binding}`, `{TemplateBinding}`...)

Ok, so I make this sample here to test `TemplateBinding` and works well:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="100">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image Source="image.png" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Now I tried the same but with others properties:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="100" Content="image.png">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

In the first case, the binding occurs perfectly. But in the second nothing happens.

What I'm missing here? There is some properties that can be bind others can't?

I'm really lost here, can someone explain to me why one works and the other not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bindings should have matching types. `Button.Content` is an `object` while `Image.Source` expects an `Uri`. Instead of `Content` use `Tag` and convert it via a converter:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="100" Tag="image.png">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Tag, Converter={StaticResource ObjectToUriConverter}}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

**Converter**

```
public class ObjectToUriConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        return new Uri(value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`TemplateBinding` is evaluated at compile time and does not provide automatic value type conversion (in this case `string` to `ImageSource`). Just use `TemplatedParent` relative source binding instead

```
<Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" />
```

Another thing, not directly related to this problem, is that if you want to use `TemplateBinding` for other properties of the same type make sure you set `TargetType` accordingly. `TemplateBinding` is evaluated against `ControlTemplate` type and default `TargetType` is `System.Windows.Controls.Control`

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
```

Comment: Your answer help me much to understand bindings + 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might get the `Content is not recognised or is not accssible error` , rather than you can use `<Image Source="{Binding Content,ElementName=btn}" />` where `btn` is the `Button Name.`